# Why the acitvity will show this weird behavior?

Tags: android

Some times, The DialtactsActivity's launching will show this strange behavior:

```
onCreate
   ||
onResume
   ||
onDestroy
   ||
onCreate
```

.......

Anyone know this scenario? Give me some hint? Maybe some abnormal thing happened?
Thanks very much!

Comment: What's in your onResume?

Comment: Are you calling same activity again in `onResume()` by calling `startActivity`?

Comment: In DialtactsActivity.java of Contacts.apk, there is no special onResume.

Comment: maybe it is because of startActivityForResult on the onMenuItemClick()

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a CONFIGURATION_CHANGED event, it trigger the procedure of relaunching the current activity.

```
com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.relaunchActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:4313)
com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.ensureActivityConfigurationLocked(ActivityStack.java:4264)
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:13528)
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateConfiguration(ActivityManagerService.java:13430)
```